# DNS redirects tracker.thepiratebay.org to 127.0.0.1

Tags: dns, hosts, tracker

I tried pinging "tracker.thepiratebay.org" and for some reason the DNS returns 127.0.0.1
I get 0% packet loss, but, obviously, it isn't going to the correct website.

My college uses a local DNS server, but I don't think that's where the problem is, since I asked a friend outside my college, and he reported the same results.

Can someone verify this result? And if yes, is there a reason? Also, can I access the real website somehow? (So, someone who can give me the ip of the website would be appreciated)

(Btw, "http://tracker.thepiratebay.org/announce" is one of the default trackers used by torrents downloaded from The Pirate Bay.)

EDIT: I've tried using the google DNS lookup instead of my own, and that too is returning `127.0.0.1` Can a possible explanation be that the site doesn't exist any more? or would not-existing return some other identifiable result?

Comment: check your C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file on windows or /etc/hosts on a *nix box. check your /etc/resolv.conf for a correct dns setting and so on.

Comment: this can also mean some kind of protection. but there're only rumors right now nothing exact to be said. you can google for this problem :)

Comment: Concerning the edit: no, the result would be an `NXDOMAIN` status to the request if the domain did not exist in the DNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

```
The Pirate Bay used to run a tracker, but has since disabled it,
although the website remains as a torrent index.
```

Also a quick `nslookup tracker.thepiratebay.org` confirms your problem.

Comment: `nslookup tracker.thepiratebay.org 8.8.8.8` gives me the same answer as my local DNS. 8.8.8.8 is the google DNS lookup
[link](http://imgur.com/AV5tQ)

Comment: I think the problem is that the tracker is no longer enabled, so they simply changed the DNS entry to make it unreachable, that's all.

Comment: @Narrakan Does that mean the site is completely disabled? If not, how would one get around this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

It's as simple as doing a `whois` on `thepiratebay.org` and you'll get the list of nameservers registered for the domain, (excerpt):

> Name Server:NS0.THEPIRATEBAY.ORG
>   Name Server:NS1.THEPIRATEBAY.ORG
>   Name Server:NS2.THEPIRATEBAY.ORG
>   Name Server:NS3.THEPIRATEBAY.ORG
>   Name Server:NS4.THEPIRATEBAY.ORG

Query one of the responsible nameservers to make sure it's not a faulty configuration on your local machine or your DNS.
`192.121.86.162` is the IP of `ns0.thepiratebay.org`:

```
dig @192.121.86.162 tracker.thepiratebay.org
```

`@` specifies that `dig` should do a direct query to the particular server. It's possible to block this, so it might not be absolutely 100% foolproof, but anyway:

```
; > DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 > @192.121.86.162 tracker.thepiratebay.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tracker.thepiratebay.org.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tracker.thepiratebay.org. 3600  IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
thepiratebay.org.       86400   IN      NS      ns0.thepiratebay.org.
thepiratebay.org.       86400   IN      NS      ns1.thepiratebay.org.
thepiratebay.org.       86400   IN      NS      ns2.thepiratebay.org.
thepiratebay.org.       86400   IN      NS      ns3.thepiratebay.org.
thepiratebay.org.       86400   IN      NS      ns4.thepiratebay.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns0.thepiratebay.org.   86400   IN      A       192.121.86.162
ns1.thepiratebay.org.   86400   IN      A       109.201.134.21
ns2.thepiratebay.org.   86400   IN      A       109.201.131.4
ns3.thepiratebay.org.   86400   IN      A       217.75.120.120
ns4.thepiratebay.org.   86400   IN      A       194.71.107.1

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 192.121.86.162#53(192.121.86.162)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan 24 21:00:34 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 228
```

The important part being

```
tracker.thepiratebay.org. 3600  IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

Comment: That's my point. It's saying that the IP of tracker.thepiratebay.org is 127.0.0.1, which makes no sense.

Comment: @shashwat: Well, sense or no sense, it is intentional and is not due to any faulty DNS or the like.

Comment: @shashwat: Also, some DNS servers won't allow names to resolve to reserved IP:s, so other servers might give different results, but that's, as they say, another story altogether.

Comment: @shashwat: Just noticed that you also asked about the website, presumably `thepiratebay.org`, this is unaffected by the DNS records for `tracker.thepiratebay.org` and should resolve normally, if it doesn't someone's probably blocking it for you.

Comment: No, I apologize for the lack of clarity, but what I meant to ask was, if I can get the actual IP of `tracker.thepiratebay.org`, I can use that directly, bypassing the need for a DNS lookup.

Comment: @shashwat: Provided that the tracker is in fact running, and has not been removed (as the answer by Narrakan) suggests, it would merely be a question of editing your `host` file and add the proper entry. However, the actual status of `tracker.thepiratebay.org` is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Run a nslookup, and see what server is returning the 127.0.0.1 address. On Windows, you would do this by running `nslookup tracker.thepiratebay.org` from a command prompt.

The 127.0.0.1 address is also known as the loopback address, however you are resolving `tracker.thepiratebay.org` is being resolved to the loopback address so you can't easily get to it. The response from nslookup will tell you who it is that is blocking it.

Comment: `nslookup tracker.thepiratebay.org 8.8.8.8` gives me the same answer as my local DNS. 8.8.8.8 is the google DNS lookup
[link](http://imgur.com/AV5tQ)